# Dependency Injection контейнеры - как получить конкретный инстанс объекта?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

Например, у меня есть класс Repository для получения данных из базы, и есть несколько классов сервисов, пусть будет Service1, Service2, Service3.

У меня будет несколько инстансов Repository, например, для двух или трёх баз.
И, должна быть возможность настраивать сервисы на работу с конкретной базой.

Не могу понять, как реализовать данные зависимости с помощью Dependency Injection контейнера.

Насколько я понял, я могу зарегистрировать сервис Repository либо как Singleton, либо будет создаваться новый инстанс на каждую зависимость.

Но, мне нужно только два репозитория Repository("DB1"), Repository("DB2), и, при создании инстанса сервиса я должен иметь возможность выбирать с какой базой работать.
То есть, как вариант - Service1(Repository("DB1")), Service2(Repository("DB1")), Service1(Repository("DB2")).

Например:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var connectionStringDb1 = "DB1 connection string";
        var connectionStringDb2 = "DB2 connection string";

        var repositoryDb1 = new Repository(connectionStringDb1);
        var repositoryDb2 = new Repository(connectionStringDb2);

        var smsSendService1 = new SmsSendService(repositoryDb1);
        var smsSendService2 = new SmsSendService(repositoryDb2);
        var emailSendService1 = new EmailSendService(repositoryDb1);

        smsSendService1.Run();

        var tasks = new Task[]
        {
            smsSendService1.Run(),
            smsSendService2.Run(),
            emailSendService1.Run()
        };

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }
}

public class Repository
{
    private string _connectionString;
    public Repository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public object GetData()
    {
        // Получаем данные из базы
        var data = ...;
        return data;
    }
}

public class SmsSendService
{
    private readonly Repository _repository;
    public SmsSendService(Repository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public Task Run()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Отправляем СМС-ки в цикле
            while (true)
            {
                var data = _repository.GetData();
                // ...
                Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        });
    }
}

public class EmailSendService
{
    private readonly Repository _repository;
    public EmailSendService(Repository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public Task Run()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Отправляем Email в цикле
            while (true)
            {
                var data = _repository.GetData();
                // ...
                Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ну да, в целом; у вас какой-то конкретный язык/фреймворк?

Comment: Я использую C# и Autofac, но, можно примеры на любом другом языке. У разных контейнеров разные возможности - хотелось бы в принципе понять, как разрешаются такие зависимости.

Comment: Попробуйте [тут](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) посмотреть (с autofac не имел дела, но выглядит похоже на то как это делается в ninject).